# Pagamentos em React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native, pagamento-online

para pagamentos in app, qual a melhor soluçao ? Vi que nenhuma operadora possui packages para React Native.. estou tentando criar uma loja online, mas estou parando nessa parte.. obrigado!!

Answer (score 3):

Acho que vai ser complicado você encontrar um SDK para React-Native, talvez tenha um pacote de alguma integração, mas acho complicado.

Recomendações:
1 - Criar um servidor WEB (onde fará a integração), criar uma API e conectar seu APP. Lembrem-se que a Loja da apple só aceita conexões HTTPS.

2 - Criar uma integração através de redirecionamento, levando para o site da empresa de pagamentos, utilizando uma WEB View.

Não menos importante. Receber pagamentos é muito mais que integrar, depende de taxas, modelo de negócio, etc. Recomendo dar uma lida.
https://pluga.co/blog/financeiro/meios-de-pagamento-e-commerce/